# SQL Server - Using ISNULL to eliminate NULL reading

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, isnull

I have completed a query, and it runs fine. Now I am working to modify it so that the output shows `[$0]` instead of `NULL`.
Does anyone know exactly how to to that?

This is what I did:

```
Select  I.Store
      , I.ISNULL([Inventory $ TOTAL],0)
      , S.ISNULL([Sales $     TOTAL],0)
      , R.ISNULL([Receipts $ TOTAL],0) 
From 
     ( Select   Store
             , '$'+Cast(Sum(QTY*Cost) As Varchar(20)) [Inventory $   TOTAL]
      From Inventory Group By Store
      ) I
Left Outer Join
     ( Select Store
           , '$'+Cast(Sum(QTY*Unit_Price) As Varchar(20)) [Sales $  TOTAL]
      From Sales Group By Store
     ) S 
         On S.Store = I.Store 
Left Outer Join
    ( Select  Store
            , '$'+Cast(Sum(QTY*Unit_Cost) As Varchar(20)) [Receipts $  TOTAL]
      From Receipts Group By Store
    ) R 
         On R.Store = I.Store
```

-- Here is the Output

```
    Store   Inventory TOTAL   SALES TOTAL   RECEIPTS TOTAL
     01       $852.94          $12371.41       $1015.16 
     02       $4192.21          $3714.74       NULL
     03       $215.73           NULL           NULL
```

Comment: ISNULL() just like you did is a good solution when you are testing a single value.  COALESCE is great when you want the first null value of more than just 1. You probably can write your entire query in one statment with a left join on store between your tables but that is something to learn yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select  I.Store
      , '$'+ ISNULL(Cast(Sum(I.QTY * I.Cost)       As Varchar(20)) , '0') AS [Inventory $   TOTAL]
      , '$'+ ISNULL(Cast(Sum(S.QTY * S.Unit_Price) As Varchar(20)) , '0') AS [Sales $  TOTAL]
      , '$'+ ISNULL(Cast(Sum(R.QTY * R.Unit_Cost)  As Varchar(20)) , '0') AS [Receipts $  TOTAL]
From Inventory I
Left Outer Join Sales    S On S.Store = I.Store 
Left Outer Join Receipts R On R.Store = I.Store 
GROUP BY I.Store
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali. It is exactly how it should be. I was configuring the query to incorporate the ideas from Matt. However, I saw that you wrote something; so I gave it a test. Thank you so much

Comment: It seems like this is going to produce a partial cross join, unless `Store` is unique in `Inventory`, `Sales` and `Receipts` tables.  And thats going to cause the values returned for the SUM aggregates to be inflated, as compared to the return from the OP query.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem you are having is a typing problem.  The subqueries explicitly cast each value to a character, so you should use a character for the `NULL` default:

```
Select I.Store,
       COALESCE(I.[Inventory $ TOTAL], '$0'),
       COALESCE(S.[Sales $     TOTAL], '$0'),
       COALESCE(R.[Receipts $ TOTAL], '$0')
```

I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()`, because `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard.

Comment: WOW! Thank you. After seeing your comment @Gordon Linoff, I rewrote (streamlined) my query as follows(it worked):Select  I.Store,
           Coalesce (Sum(I.QTY * I.Cost), '$0') As [Inventory $  TOTAL],
           Coalesce (Sum(S.QTY * S.Unit_Price), '$0') As [Inventory $      TOTAL],
    Coalesce (Sum(R.QTY * R.Unit_Cost), '$0') As [Inventory $  TOTAL]
        From Inventory I
    Left Outer Join Sales S
    On S.Store = I.Store 
    Left Outer Join Receipts R 
    On R.Store = I.Store 
    Group by I.Store

Comment: @stopa: The rewritten query is going to produce a partial cross product, and inflate the values of the SUM() aggregates. You had it right in the original query, separate inline views to do the aggregates from each of the tables, and then join the single row for each store.  I suggest you have the inline views return just the plain numeric value, and then handle the formatting in the outer query, *after* you handle the replacement of the NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Have each of the inline views return the plain numeric value. In the outer query, wrap the numeric value from each inline view in the SQL Server ISNULL function (or the ANSI COALESCE function), and then do the formatting around that. Handle all the conversions and formatting in the outermost query.

```
  SELECT i.store
       , '$'+CAST( ISNULL(i.si_total,0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS  [Inventory $   TOTAL]
       , '$'+CAST( ISNULL(s.ss_total,0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS  [Sales $  TOTAL]
       , '$'+CAST( ISNULL(r.sr_total,0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS  [Receipts $  TOTAL]
    FROM ( SELECT si.Store
                , SUM(si.QTY*si.Cost)         AS si_total
             FROM Inventory si
            GROUP BY si.Store
         ) i
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT ss.Store
                , SUM(ss.QTY*ss.Unit_Price)   AS ss_total
             FROM Sales ss
            GROUP BY ss.Store
         ) s
      ON s.Store = i.Store
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT sr.Store
                , SUM(sr.QTY*sr.Unit_Cost)    AS sr_total
             FROM Receipts sr
            GROUP BY sr.Store
         ) r
      ON r.Store = i.Store
   ORDER BY i.Store
```

Comment: You have shown me yet another way to write this query, @Spencer7593. I am becoming an expert in using ISNULL in MS SQL administration. Thank you.

Comment: This query differs *significantly* from the query in the M.Ali's answer (the selected answer.) As I commented on that answer, that query is gong to produce a partial cross product, which is going to return too many rows (which are then aggregated.) The query in this answer doesn't do that.